# Pandas styler Jupyter-lab output differs to VS code Juypter output

Tags: pandas, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am not much of a coder but I know that the look of a summary table is important to people who are time-poor and want to quickly see what you are saying (if anything).

A styles dictionary I've put together works more or less as promised in Jupyter-lab see the first screenshot.

[image: Screenshot 1]

But renders differently in VS Code (Jupyter notebook), see photo 2.

[image: Photo 2]

In particular, the borders (row bottom borders to emulate Bloomber style) don't show. Questions: why is this? Is there a VS code setting that will have the borders displayed in the VS Code Jupyter? I prefer to work in VS Code but may have to give it up.

The styles dictionary used:

```
# itk teal style for data frame doesn't print the borders properly in vscode but does in jupyter
styles = [dict(selector="caption",
       props = [("text-align", "left"),
              ("font-size", "150%"),
              ("color", 'white'),
              ("background-color", "teal")]),
              dict(selector = "",props =[("color","grey"),("background-color",'white'),('border-bottom', '1px dotted grey')]),
              dict(selector = "th",props =[("background-color",'white'),('border-bottom', '1px dotted grey'),('min_width','300px')]),
              dict(selector = "tr",props =[("background-color",'white'),('border-bottom', '1px dotted grey'),("color","black")]), # !!!!
              dict(selector = ".blank",props =[("background-color",'#00DCDC')]),
              dict(selector = "tfoot",props =[("background-color",'red')]),
              dict(selector = "th.col_heading",props =[("color",'black'),('font-size','110%'),("background-color",'#00DCDC')]),
              dict( selector = "tr:last-child", props =[("color","black"),('border-bottom', '5px black')])]
```

And the line that calls the styler:

```
price_sum.style .format ('{:,.0f}').set_caption("Price summary $/MWh").set_table_styles(styles)
```

Comment: This is a common query. The output from pandas styler is, for the most part basic HTML with <table> tags. Different browers or viewer applications apply their own default CSS to interpret, color, highlight, bold, certain HTML elements or rows. To be certain of the output, view the output as raw HTML in a browser and ensure it appears as required. Then, go back and visualise the output in your desired software (VScode). If it doesn't work either VS code is not displaying properly, or it uses its default CSS with a higher priority and overwrites yours.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I agree. My code  works in Jupyter Labs but not in VS Code. Is there a way to change the default CSS in VS Code? Some global variable as there is for chart displays.